# How to call this url using Only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I have this url which get list of objects as a xml

https://test/ab

I want to call this using only javascript 
I try this

```
function loadXMLDoc() {


    xhttp.open("GET", "https://test/ab", true);


    }
    xhttp.send();
    }
```

please help

It gives status correct and ready state correct but it give me the responseText is empty

but when I try this url on my browser it works fine

Comment: It will depend on whether it supports CORS

Comment: If CORS is not enabled you can't use ajax to get content of the page that have different domain.

Comment: how can I know that this is support CORS? @ArunPJohny

Comment: @jcubic So what shall I DO?

Comment: your second `onreadystatechange` will overwrite the first one. you need to put that document line where your comment is right now. and open the developer tools see any errors.

Comment: @RolandStarke   developer tools say that error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://portal.test.net/Qest/api/groups/2/members/inable/ab. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:61914' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You can check network tab in developer tools to see if CORS is enabled (Access-Control-Allow-Origin header) if it's not present then the only option is to create server side proxy script that will read the content of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CORS is the problem try [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) addon in Chrome. You can go through this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) to know more possible solutions to this problem.

Comment: Sorry can't understand what you mean

Comment: but you should note that the site will only work for you then (or others that have this addon), so i would not recommend it

Comment: Yes, thats one of the problems with this method.

Comment: @Ankur It works for me on chrome only now after add the extension

Comment: Please refer to this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) to know possible solutions to this problem.
If you want to make it work on other browsers, you'll have to install similar addons for them as well. Also remember that this addon only resolves this issue on your browser ( as Ronald stated).